# Split a string by a byte

Tags: java, string, split

I have a `String` which has some ASCII control characters in it (namely `RS` (0x1e) and `US` (0x1f)). I have defined them in my code as such:

```
static public final byte RS  = 0x1E;
static public final byte US  = 0x1F;
```

later in my code, I want to split a string using these characters:

```
String[] records = content.split(String.valueOf(RS));
```

but, that doesn't work correctly. After some fiddling I found that this

```
String[] records = content.split("\u001e");
```

does work, but in that case, I have to remember the codes. I do use the `RS` static byte also in other parts, so just changing that is not a real option. I could of course create a `RS_STRING` or something, but that means double work.

Any clean good solution for this?

Comment: Why not just use `public static final String RS_STRING = new String(new byte[] { RS }, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`?

Comment: `split()` takes a regex, you may need to escape the value with `Pattern.compile()`?

Comment: @berry120 there's no special characters in his sequence.

Comment: @MarounMaroun My bad, I misread the latter half of the question. Declaring RS as a char (rather than a byte) may well be the issue?

Comment: Side note: https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.8.7-modifiers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declaring the character as a `char` rather than a `byte` fixed it for me - the following works fine:

```
char RS  = 0x1E;
String s = new String(new char[]{'d', RS, 'e'});
System.out.println(s.split(String.valueOf(RS)).length); //Prints 2
```

However, using a byte as the type causes it to fail:

```
byte RS  = 0x1E;
String s = new String(new char[]{'d', (char)RS, 'e'});
System.out.println(s.split(String.valueOf(RS)).length); //Prints 1
```

You can of course cast the `char` back to `byte` if you need to refer to it as such in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your use of `String.valueOf()`, because there *is no String.valueOf(byte)*.

Instead the byte gets silently widened to an `int` and `String.valueOf(int)` is called. And this method returns the decimal string representation of the int.

Thats why the suggestion of declaring RS as a char fixes it, String.valueOf(char) indeed does what you expect (gives a String with that char in it).

You could alternately just add an explicit cast when transforming to the String representation: `String.valueOf((char) RS)` and keep the costant RS declared as a byte.